# To find the length of the splitted sequence in r

Tags: r

I want to count the number of characters in between two patterns
for eg:

```
seq="AATTGGCCATGCAATTGGCCATTAAA"
pattern="ATGC|CCAT"
```

I want the pieces to be

```
"AATTGGCC" "AATTGG" "TAAA"
```

And then I want to find the length of these splitted pieces.

Comment: To measure the length of the piece use `nchar` function.

Comment: the problem is i couldnt split it based on two patterns simultaneously

Comment: The problem is that the second pattern split occurs "AATTGG"

Comment: Actually i just gave it as an example i have to cut on a bigger sequence if someone can understand my question and reply a code for any sequence with more than two patterns I would be thankful

Comment: Are you trying to do an RE digestion? You should look into the package `Biostrings` and the function `vmatchPattern`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `for` loop

```
for(nm in pat){
 seq <- gsub(nm, " ", seq)
}

res <- scan(text=seq, sep="", what="", quiet=TRUE)
res
#[1] "AATTGGCC" "AATTGG"   "TAAA"    
nchar(res)
#[1] 8 6 4
```

#### data

```
seq="AATTGGCCATGCAATTGGCCATTAAA"
pat <- c("ATGC", "CCAT")
```

Comment: Here order is mattering.

Comment: @user2100721  You are right.  In your nested solution also, the order matters, right?

Comment: @Roland I thought it is for some other purpose (though the `urgent` implied something sinister).

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun its a timely help thank you soo much

Comment: @akrun : Yes, I am also stuck their.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
spilt_seq <- unlist(str_split(str_split("AATTGGCCATGCAATTGGCCATTAAA",pattern="ATGC")[[1]],pattern = "CCAT"))
split_seq
```

Then use `nchar` to measure the length

```
nchar(split_seq)
```

Comment: thank you but It has to run in a loop so everytimei cant be giving the pattern one by one suppose i have more than 10 patterns it is not possible to give it one by one. So is there any other way?

Comment: Actually, there is another problem. You want a specific output, that's why I gave you the previous code. If you run this `unlist(str_split(str_split("AATTGGCCATGCAATTGGCCATTAAA",pattern="CCAT")[[1]],pattern = "ATGC"))`, you will get other kind of output.

Comment: yes i can get it but then i have to submit the code by today. so is there any other way?

Comment: Is there any other way around like just to get the length of characters in between patterns without splitting like

Comment: Eg: seq= "ATGATGCATGCATTATG"

Comment: pattern="ATGC|CATT" such that the length of the first split be 3 second 0 like that

Comment: `strsplit("ATGATGCATGCATTATG", "ATGC|CATT")` returns you probably what you want `"ATG", "", "ATTATG"`? Then just apply `nchar`

Comment: @Roland : I am not doing. Just trying to figure out the solution.